# Unable to update slug in Craft 3 for single enteries

Tags: entry, craft3, slug, entry-slug

I have created some entries for type single but now I am not able to update their slug even I have updated the title

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the URI format in your section for the specific language.

Go to `settings -> sections -> your single section`, there you'll have a table below and you can insert the URI format you like for every site.